# Django - SyntaxError at URL file

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm having a syntax error with Django (Django 1.8, Python 3.4) in my base URL. Here's the code for ir:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from login_vacations import views as login_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', login_views.index, name="login_vacations"),
    url(r'^logout/$', login_views.logout_vacations, name='logout_vacations'),
    url(r'^vacations/', include('vacations_app.urls')),
]
```

The vacations_app exists on the folder and it does have a urls.py file inside of it. The error is the following:

```
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 10)
```

Instead, if i remove the single quotes from the include function, the error will be:

```
name 'vacations_app' is not defined
```

If i erase line 10 entirely, the application will work normally. But i do not understand why. The structure on this line is exactly the same as the one on line 7 (the one which includes the admin urls).

The vacations_app/urls.py has the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from vacations_app import views as vacations_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', vacations_views.vacations_public_view, name='vacations_public_view'),
    url(r'^my_vacations/$', vacations_views.my_vacations, name='my_vacations'),
    url(r'^new_vacation/$', vacations_views.new_vacation, name='new_vacation'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/$'), vacations_views.show_vacation, name='show_vacation'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/add_destination/$'), vacations_views.add_destination_to_vacation, name='add_destination_to_vacation'),
    ]
```

The full trace of the error can be found here: http://dpaste.com/2A1B6DS

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are the contents of `vacations_app/urls.py`?

Comment: did you added vacations_app in installed_apps of settings.py?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback for your error?

Comment: I edited the question to provide more details as you guys asked

Comment: @Alasdair
 
I edited the question to include it

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I edited the question to include it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two additional close parentheses in your vacations_app/urls.py on lines 10 and 11. Right now you have:

```
url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/$'), vacations_views.show_vacation, name='show_vacation'),
url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/add_destination/$'), vacations_views.add_destination_to_vacation, name='add_destination_to_vacation'),
```

They should look like:

```
url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/$', vacations_views.show_vacation, name='show_vacation'),
url(r'^show/(?P<vacation_id>\w+)/add_destination/$', vacations_views.add_destination_to_vacation, name='add_destination_to_vacation'),
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you added the application (vacations_app) as `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`? I am also a bit skeptical of your `urlpatterns = []` because I have `urlpatterns = patterns()` on some of my project.

Can you share your `settings.py` (with identifiable information omitted) if possible?

Comment: This should be a comment. In any case, neither of these can be the cause of a syntax error.

Comment: Using a list instead of the patterns `function` is the new preferred way to declare url patterns (cf [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#syntax-of-the-urlpatterns-variable))

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ideally I would have commented but I could not because my reputation was 46 when I posted earlier.

I think that Joey Wilhelm has hit the nail on its head.